# SPB is inaccessible: SCO OpenServer Migration

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, sco

I have an old SCO OpenServer (5.0.7) UNIX server running archaic proprietary software and we are trying to virtualize it through Fedora KVM. We have successfully gotten it to boot simply by dding the hard drive from the old server to a file and then converting it to a VHD file via VirtualBox tools. But after booting and logging in we get an error saying `SPB is inaccessible; check the seed <F1> screen.` and then sends the user back to the login screen.

I have lots more information about the previous setup but decided to hold it back as to not bog down with unnecessary info. Any tips, pointers, advice, etc is greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.